# Selfmade Font from MyScriptFont.com dont works

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've created a own font with http://www.myscriptfont.com/ but this does not appear on my website. My code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontName';
    src: url('fonts/MyFontName.otf');
    src: url('fonts/MyFontName.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

MyFontName {
  color: #df0000;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: 1.5rem; 
  font-family: MyFontName;
    font-size: 35px;
}
```

what am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot for your help!
Greetings from germany

Comment: The question lacks essential information. Does the font work when installed as a local font? Which browser(s) did you use for testing? How can others test your font?

Answer (score 0):

The way you created the class is wrong. May be this cause issue.

Instead of this:

```
  MyFontName {
   color: #df0000;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-size: 1.5rem; 
   font-family: MyFontName;
   font-size: 35px;
 }
```

Use like this:

```
 .CustomClass{
  color: #df0000;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: 1.5rem; 
  font-family: MyFontName;
  font-size: 35px;
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="CustomClass">My Sample Text Goes Here</div>
```